# Python SQL alchemy non relationship joins one to many

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm using a singer postgres target found [here](https://github.com/transferwise/pipelinewise-target-postgres)Which puts me in an odd position. I don't believe I can define relationships on the tables it creates. This is causing me much grief when i'm trying to craft queries using these tables.

I have a basic join like this

```
query = (
        db.query(
            table_1,
            table_2
        ).join(
            table_2,
            table_2.object_id = table_1.id
        )
    )
```

There is an artificial one to many relationship between table_1 and table_2.
The output of this join looks like this...

```
    [
        {
            "table_1_id": "12345",
            "table_2_data": "foo"
        },
        {
            "table_1_id": "12345",
            "table_2_data": "bar"
        }
    ]
```

What I want the output to look like is this....

```
    [
        {
            "table_1_id": "12345",
            "table_2_data": [
                {"data": "foo"}, 
                {"data": "bar"}
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I've tried to do group_by but have had no luck figuring it out since i need to group by every selected column.

I've tried to do subqueryload but this does not work as there is no defined relationship.

I've also tried to do distinct which kind of works but I only end up with 1 of the 2 entries for the table_2 data.

Comment: in your outer select of table 1 you want a column that is a sub-select of table 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JonSG I was able to solve my problem by using the following in my query() function

```
query(
    table_1,
    select([table_2]).where(table_2.table_1_id == 
        table_1.id).correlate(table_1).subquery()
)
```